# Ember GET to Rails backend

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js, routes

I have this json rails api endpoing that response to GET-last-problems => /api/v1/last-problems

```
{"last_problems": [
    {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Who are you?",
    "description": ""
},
{
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Who are they?",
    "description": ""
}
}
```

and when from ember I call to last-problems I have this:

```
GET http://localhost:3000/api/v1/lastProblems 404 (Not Found)
Error while processing route: last_problems.index Adapter operation failed Error: Adapter operation failed
```

I read that Ember camelize and clean rails routes.

Do I need an adapter? Where do I have to created it?

Comment: Is `last_problems` defined in `routes.rb`?

Comment: Yes, I defined and I can access with curl http://localhost:3000/api/v1/last_problems

Answer (score 0):

The url you it works is [localhost:3000/api/v1/last_problems](http://localhost:3000/api/v1/last_problems) and the one Ember is trying to get is [localhost:3000/api/v1/lastproblems](http://localhost:3000/api/v1/lastproblems) without the `_` you probably defined lastproblems without the `_` on Ember.

Comment: No, Ember has a property that underscore and camelize its request to rails app. Me question is about best practices and if I need and adapter in my ember app without change rails backend.